# Why does my Express.js BackEnd delete a cookie successfully in Chrome, but not in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, httponly

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822566/cookie-deletes-in-chrome-but-not-firefox) question my code is not identical to the cookie, but it seems to be identical. Here is my cookie setting code:

```
res.cookie(
    'access_token', 'Bearer '+ token, {
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), // cookie will be removed after 15 mins
      httpOnly: true
    })
```

Here is my cookie deletion code:

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  res.clearCookie('access_token', { domain:'localhost', path: '/', httpOnly: true })
  .redirect('http://localhost:4200/avior/login')
});
```

According to the Express JS API documentation the expiration/maxAge should not be set in the clearCookie method. That's exactly what I did. Is this a problem only because I use httpOnly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even I faced a similar problem in my angular project. I solved my issue by setting path:"/" 
while both creating and deleting cookies as below

```
res.cookie(
  'access_token', 'Bearer '+ token, {
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), // cookie will be removed after 15 mins
  httpOnly: true,
  path: '/'
})
```

Comment: Yes, I've set the domain AND path and now it works! Weird, because the default values should be ok.

Comment: the domain was unnecessary, your answer is correct.